# How to make the span to fill empty space on current line and continue to show remaining text on next line

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox

In the below code snippet example, after marked word  `science` and `theory` there is a empty space at the end. Forcing the next span element to appear on the newline.

How to make the `next span element after marked word to fill the empty space`. and then the remaining words of that span should continue display on new line?

So that the whole text looks like a description with tagged words on it.

[image]

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<style>
mark{
display:flex;
flex-direction:column-reverse;
}

div{
 display:flex;
 flex-flow: row wrap;
 align-items: flex-end
}
</style>
<body>

<div dir="auto" style="line-height: 2.5;">
  <span data-start_offset="0" data-end="41" style="white-space: break-spaces;">Metaphysics continues asking "why" where </span>
  <span>
    <span style="display: flex;">
      <mark id="06aabd50-2b2a-4b45-bb5a-311630c7b2e8" data-start_offset="41" data-end="48" style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0); background: rgb(173, 164, 189); opacity: 1; position: relative; padding: 0px 4px; cursor: pointer;">science 
      
      <span style="font-size: 0.7em; line-height: 1.5; background-color: rgb(173, 164, 189); opacity: 1; left: 0px; padding: 0px 5px; font-style: italic; pointer-events: none; top: -11px; font-weight: bold; margin-left: 0px; white-space: nowrap; overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis;">class1</span>
      
        <span style="font-size: 0.7em; line-height: 1.5; background-color: rgb(173, 164, 189); opacity: 1; left: 0px; padding: 0px 5px; font-style: italic; pointer-events: none; top: -11px; font-weight: bold; margin-left: 0px; white-space: nowrap; overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis;">class2</span>
      </mark>
      <button class="MuiButtonBase-root MuiIconButton-root MuiIconButton-sizeSmall" tabindex="0" type="button" aria-label="delete" style="
    align-items: flex-end;
"><span class="MuiIconButton-label"><svg class="MuiSvgIcon-root MuiSvgIcon-fontSizeInherit" focusable="false" viewBox="0 0 24 24" aria-hidden="true"><path d="M20 12l-1.41-1.41L13 16.17V4h-2v12.17l-5.58-5.59L4 12l8 8 8-8z"></path></svg></span><span class="MuiTouchRipple-root"></span></button>
    </span>
  </span>
  <span data-start_offset="48" data-end="194" style="white-space: break-spaces;"> of fundamental physics is based of fundamental physics is based of fundamental physics is based</span>
  <span>
    <span style="position: relative;">
      <mark id="977c207e-92ca-4176-af01-0b6b01afe578" data-start_offset="78" data-end="84" style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0); background: rgb(231, 131, 210); opacity: 1; position: relative; padding: 0px 4px; cursor: pointer;">theory 
      
      <span style="font-size: 0.7em; line-height: 1.5; background-color: rgb(231, 131, 210); opacity: 1; left: 0px; padding: 0px 5px; font-style: italic; pointer-events: none; top: -11px; font-weight: bold; margin-left: 0px; white-space: nowrap; overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis;">class3</span>
      
        <span style="font-size: 0.7em; line-height: 1.5; background-color: rgb(231, 131, 210); opacity: 1; left: 0px; padding: 0px 5px; font-style: italic; pointer-events: none; top: -11px; font-weight: bold; margin-left: 0px; white-space: nowrap; overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis;">class4</span>
      </mark>
    </span>
  </span>
  <span data-start_offset="84" data-end="194" style="white-space: break-spaces;"> of fundamental physics is based on some set.</span>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you give a sketch/idea of what you are trying to achieve? I believe it can be coded in simpler easier way. (in-line styling is making it difficult to get insights from  the code)

Comment: @firstuser I suggest you to run the above code snippet. you just have to click on `run code snippet`. In that paragraph I have marked two words and coz of that the the text breakdown and moved to new line. It no longer looks like a paragraph. now I need to remove those empty space to make it look like a proper paragraph. got It?

Comment: @firstuser also I have uploaded the annotated image for better understanding. kindly, have a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `display: flex` from the outer `<div>` and use `display: inline-flex;` to make your span elements display inline like a `<span>`.

`display: flex;` makes the element display as a block element (i.e. it will behave like a `<div>` which is what you're seeing).

Here is a simplified version of your markup showing where to make the change:

```
<!-- use `display: inline-flex;` instead -->
<span style="display: flex;">
  <mark id="06aabd50-2b2a-4b45-bb5a-311630c7b2e8" ...>science 
  
  <span style="...">class1</span>
  
  <span style="...">class2</span>
  </mark>
  <button class="MuiButtonBase-root ..."></button>
</span>
```

Updated to use `inline-flex`:

```
<span style="display: inline-flex;">
  <mark id="06aabd50-2b2a-4b45-bb5a-311630c7b2e8" ...>science 
  ...
</span>
```

Here's a runnable example:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<style>
mark{
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column-reverse;
}

</style>
<body>

<div dir="auto" style="line-height: 2.5;">
  <span data-start_offset="0" data-end="41" style="white-space: break-spaces;">Metaphysics continues asking "why" where </span>
  <span>
    <span style="display: inline-flex;">
      <mark id="06aabd50-2b2a-4b45-bb5a-311630c7b2e8" data-start_offset="41" data-end="48" style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0); background: rgb(173, 164, 189); opacity: 1; position: relative; padding: 0px 4px; cursor: pointer;">science 
      
      <span style="font-size: 0.7em; line-height: 1.5; background-color: rgb(173, 164, 189); opacity: 1; left: 0px; padding: 0px 5px; font-style: italic; pointer-events: none; top: -11px; font-weight: bold; margin-left: 0px; white-space: nowrap; overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis;">class1</span>
      
        <span style="font-size: 0.7em; line-height: 1.5; background-color: rgb(173, 164, 189); opacity: 1; left: 0px; padding: 0px 5px; font-style: italic; pointer-events: none; top: -11px; font-weight: bold; margin-left: 0px; white-space: nowrap; overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis;">class2</span>
      </mark>
      <button class="MuiButtonBase-root MuiIconButton-root MuiIconButton-sizeSmall" tabindex="0" type="button" aria-label="delete" style="
    align-items: flex-end;
"><span class="MuiIconButton-label"><svg class="MuiSvgIcon-root MuiSvgIcon-fontSizeInherit" focusable="false" viewBox="0 0 24 24" aria-hidden="true"><path d="M20 12l-1.41-1.41L13 16.17V4h-2v12.17l-5.58-5.59L4 12l8 8 8-8z"></path></svg></span><span class="MuiTouchRipple-root"></span></button>
    </span>
  </span>
  <span data-start_offset="48" data-end="194" style="white-space: break-spaces;"> of fundamental physics is based of fundamental physics is based of fundamental physics is based</span>
  <span>
    <span style="display: inline-flex;">
      <mark id="977c207e-92ca-4176-af01-0b6b01afe578" data-start_offset="78" data-end="84" style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0); background: rgb(231, 131, 210); opacity: 1; position: relative; padding: 0px 4px; cursor: pointer;">theory 
      
      <span style="font-size: 0.7em; line-height: 1.5; background-color: rgb(231, 131, 210); opacity: 1; left: 0px; padding: 0px 5px; font-style: italic; pointer-events: none; top: -11px; font-weight: bold; margin-left: 0px; white-space: nowrap; overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis;">class3</span>
      
        <span style="font-size: 0.7em; line-height: 1.5; background-color: rgb(231, 131, 210); opacity: 1; left: 0px; padding: 0px 5px; font-style: italic; pointer-events: none; top: -11px; font-weight: bold; margin-left: 0px; white-space: nowrap; overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis;">class4</span>
      </mark>
    </span>
  </span>
  <span data-start_offset="84" data-end="194" style="white-space: break-spaces;"> of fundamental physics is based on some set.</span>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It's not working can u please add runnable code snippet

Comment: @VikasAcharya Updated the answer and added an example

Answer (score 0):

span is an important and widely used inline element in HTML document. It is used to contain other inline elements, or textual content. Then you can just `display:block;` to your span